# Trying to target a string with text and HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target each of the td's below after 21 and hide them. I have next to no control over the outputted HTML.  I have tried using indexOf and contains but can't seem to target the specific string. There are only 7 td's after the 21 so I can target each individually if need be.

```
<tr>
<td>19<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>20<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>21<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>1<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>2<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>3<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>4<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>5<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>6<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>7<br /><div class="Content">&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show your table attributes, please. Or at least tell us how many rows are in the table.

Comment: How are we supposed to know why it doesn't work if you don't show what you have tried? Stack Overflow is not for asking for a solution, it's for asking for help on why your solution doesn't work. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: How do you know which `td` you want to start hiding at? Do you want to examine the actual content of the cells to see which one has content that looks like "21"? Do you just want to hide the last 7 rows? Or all rows after the first 3? How do you expect to target these elements in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) overload that takes a function. That function takes the index of the element in the collection and the element, and will only return the element if the function returns true. If you have a way of identifying that specific row, it would be better (so that it doesn't delete other row's cells), but here's a couple of methods:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#kill').on('click', function() {
    // If you know it's the fourth one on you want to remove:
    $('tr > td').filter(function(index, el) {
      return index > 2;
    }).remove();
    // If you only know it's the cells after the one with "21" in it
/*
      var found = false;
    $('tr > td').filter(function(index, el) {
      var skip = false;
      if (!found) {
         found = el.textContent.substring(0, 2) == '21';
         skip = true;
      }
      return found && !skip;
    }).remove();
*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>19<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>20<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>21<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>1<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>2<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>3<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>4<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>5<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>6<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>7<br />
      <div class="Content">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="kill">Destroy the rows</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript (without any table id or row position given by you):

```
// Get row.
var row = document.getElementById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];

// Get all row cells.
var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');

// Loop through cells starting with the cell 
// at 3rd position (e.g. 4th cell) and hide them.
for (var c = 3; c < cells.length; c++) {
    var cell = cells[c];
    cell.style.display = 'none';
}
```

You'll have to change `tableId` and `tr` index 0 to what you have.
Otherwise, if you want to hide td's in each tr, then you have to loop through tr's too.